# Jenkins workspace root getting overwritten or not accepted

Tags: jenkins, root, perforce, workspace

I am implementing Jenkins into already established Perforce workflow. 
Each of the workspaces we have in Perforce(and there is a lot of them) is using the Drive letter( for example D:\ ) as the root directory for the workspace. 
I am using p4Plugin in Jenkins to sync the code before running the actual scripts. And Jenkins has it's own workspace which is being used every time I start to sync the code.

I tried using the Spec file, for workspace behavior in P4 Plugin, where I would specify the root to be D:\ but whenever it loads it will still create jenkins workspace root. 
I also tried using the Static workspace behavior, and that will work, but the problem is that in order for that workflow to work, the person needs to create a workspace manually on the worker of jenkins setup, and then create the job, which is then defeating the purpose of using jenkins at first. Plus we need a workspace per job. 
Which made me think, if I use an already existing workspace with D:\ being the root, and use a Temp workspace behavior in jenkins, that it will copy the root settings as well as other ones. But unfortunatelly it also sets the sync to be to the jenkins workspace.

In short, all I want is to be able to use the D:\ drive to sync all the code instead of putting them into the jenkins root directory and syncing the code to the project folders inside.(ex C:\JenkinsData\syncProject...)

Answer (score 1):

That's the design of the p4 plugin.  It puts the workspace where jenkins asks us to.

See property jenkins.model.Jenkins.workspacesDir here:  https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Features+controlled+by+system+properties

I don't think the default in that wiki is correct.

On all your master and slaves, you can try to change that to just D:\

That assumes your client view definitions (right hand side) will not overlap.

Otherwise:

A "form-in client" trigger script can alter the root.   The script should only change jenkins relevant clients, so you'll need to pass *something* to the script in the trigger definition to signify that it is for a jenkins job.  Examples could be a client naming convention and/or the clientip.

Your Perforce Admin, if that's not you, will have to assist.